# MatLab Save image to database using database toolbox

Tags: mysql, sql, database, matlab, ms-access-2013

Is it possible to insert or save an image to a database table using MatLab?

Here's my code:

```
%Code for Database Login
conn = database('vlmsystem','admin','vlog');
indata = imread('C:\Users\Sony Vaio\Documents\Task\0.1 Systems\System 1 - edited\Appendix\images database\auto1.jpg');
a = getframe(h);
indata = a.cdata;
hgsave(h, 'tempfile.fig')
fid = fopen('tempfile.fig', 'r')
indata = fread(fid, inf, '*uint8')
fclose(fid)
s = size(indata);
bdata = reshape(indata,[],1);
x = conn.Handle
StatementObject = x.preparestatement(insertcommand);
StatementObject.setObject(1,bdata)
StatementObject.execute
close(StatementObject)
dbpath = 'C:\Users\Sony Vaio\Documents\Task\0.1 Systems\System 1 - edited\Appendix\vlogdbase.mdb';
tableName = 'vehicleLog';
colnames = {'date_time','plate_number','login_logout','physical_feature'}
colnames1 = {'date_time'}
colnames2 = {'plate_number'}
colnames3 = {'login_logout'}
colnames4 = {'physical_feature'}
dat = datestr(now);
pltno = (f);
lilo = 'login';
physf = {bdata}
coldata = {dat,pltno,lilo,}
insert(conn,tableName,colnames,coldata);
close(conn);
```

And I am getting this error.

> Error using graphicsversion Input was not a valid graphics object
>
> Error in getframe (line 50)   usingMATLABClasses =
>   ~graphicsversion(parentFig, 'handlegraphics');
>
> Error in licenseplate>StartKnop_Callback (line 248) a = getframe(h);

Tried copying this solution but I can't seem to make it work. Here's the [link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1BYF0/).

**EDIT:** Fix Code....but... how to insert binary data into the database.
There's no binary option in the database. The result won't feed into the table.

[image]

```
%Code for Database Login
conn = database('vlmsystem','admin','vlog');
indata = imread('C:\Users\Sony Vaio\Documents\Task\0.1 Systems\System 1 - edited\Appendix\images database\auto1.jpg');
s = size(indata);
bdata = reshape(indata,[],1);
dbpath = 'C:\Users\Sony Vaio\Documents\Task\0.1 Systems\System 1 - edited\Appendix\vlogdbase.mdb';
tableName = 'vehicleLog';
colnames = {'date_time','plate_number','login_logout','physical_feature'}
colnames1 = {'date_time'}
colnames2 = {'plate_number'}
colnames3 = {'login_logout'}
colnames4 = {'physical_feature'}
dat = datestr(now);
pltno = (f);
lilo = 'login';
physf = {bdata}
coldata = {dat,pltno,lilo,physf}
insert(conn,tableName,colnames,coldata);
close(conn);
```

Comment: The error is raised by `a = getframe(h);` but we don't see what `h` is, thus no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read what you are copying.

The solution says:

> Alternatively, if you have a figure and want to save a snapshot of it, use the command below:

You copied both blocks, one that reads files, one hat uses getframe to read a frame from a handle.

Comment: I know I just copied the whole code on the link What I am trying to point is I have no idea what to put on the h, what value or whatever. But is it possible to save/insert an image to a database? Like how will it look like if it will be saved?

Comment: @Lloyd: If you understand the input from file, but not the input from handle, why are you taking both? Use the input from file and everything is fine. There is no need to fill `indata` twice.